# elastic search + filter on ffields in json format in the discovery search?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a search that returns events with a field that looks like this:

```
metric.loraCheckin.gateways
    {
  "gatewayId": "eui-647fdafffe00c1d5",
  "rssi": -97,
  "snr": 8.2
}
```

or

```
{
  "gatewayId": "eui-647fdafffe00b4fe",
  "rssi": -98,
  "snr": 5.2
},
{
  "gatewayId": "eui-647fdafffe00b4ff",
  "rssi": -101,
  "snr": 7.2
},
{
  "gatewayId": "eui-647fdafffe00c342",
  "rssi": -120,
  "snr": 1.2
}
```

Can I filter on the contents within the `metric.loraCheckin.gateways` field, for example filter `gatewayId=eui-647fdafffe00c1d5`